# Calculating Laser Beam Intensity Absorbtion

Tags: optics, energy, visible-light, laser, laser-interaction

This question pertains to the ability to calculate the laser beam intensity , at a particular point in time when using lasers for the purposes of Cutting and Engraving Materials.

The parameters at play when dealing with this equation so far are:

- Speed the laser is moving at(mm/s)
- Power of the Laser Beam (Watts)
- Diameter / Area of the focussed beam spot (mm)
- Frequency of laser pulse (Hz)
- Duration of laser pulse / rise and fall time of the pulse (ns)

Currently i believe i am able to calculate this laser energy parameter for a Constant Wave laser as follows:

---

```
diameter = 1.27 * (focalLength) * Wavelength * ((M^2) / BEAMDIA); 
beamArea = 2 * pi * (0.5 * diameter);
beamIntensity = laserAveragePower / (area * speed); // joules/mm^2
```

---

However this does not take into account many of the factors i listed above. 
So my question is: How can i adjust the above formula to include the listed parameters?

For example, how would this be modified to account for a laser being Pulsed at 100Hz, with average power 100W and a 200ns pulse duration.

I am under the impression the Frequency of the laser pulses need to be converted to a unit of measurement, such as "Pulses Per Inch".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want the beam energy? Then it shouldn't depend on the spot size. If you want the *intensity*, then it will depend on the spot size.

Comment: Yes it is the intensity. I have gotten the terms mixed up it seems.

Comment: Note that intensity is *not* measured in joules/mm^2. Intensity is a measure of energy *flow* per unit area, and as such it is measured in watts per square meter (or equivalent units).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks for pointing this out. Do you also have any idea on how i can modify the equation to incorporate the other factors?

Comment: @Brett No, I don't. I don't really know what it is you're trying to calculate here.